# html validation errors -- element meta not allowed as child of body

Tags: html, validation

I'm a newbie trying to validate a simple html page with the w3 validator, but am running into errors (see below) that seem to indicate that my body section starts before it does. Any advice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

    <head>
      <title>indexName</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name=“author” content=“My Name”>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>My Name</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href=traceroute.png>traceroute</a> </li>
        <li> <a href=command.png>command</a> </li>
        <li> <a href=document.docx>document</a> </li>
        <li> <a href=spreadsheet.xlsx>spreadsheet</a> </li>
        <li> <a href=database.accdb>database</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Errors:

> Element *meta name=“author” content=“my* not allowed as child of element *body* in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>   From line 6, column 5; to line 6, column 51
>   f-8">↩    ↩    <

and

> Stray end tag *head*.
>   From line 8, column 3; to line 8, column 9

and

> Start tag *body* seen but an element of the same type was already open. From line 10, column 3; to line 10, column 8

and

> End tag for  *body* seen, but there were unclosed elements.
>   From line 20, column 3; to line 20, column 9

and

> Unclosed element *meta name=“author” content=“silvia”.*
>   From line 6, column 5; to line 6, column 51

Comment: Your text doesn't give any of those errors (it just complains about smart quotes).

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using a rich text editor to write your HTML? Microsoft Word, for example? If so: don't. That's probably why your validation fails. Look closely at this: `<meta name=“author” content=“My Name”>`. Note the quotes? Those are not ASCII quotation marks, but they should be. Use Notepad, Notepad++, Sublime Text or any other plain text editor.

Comment: I would just change those typographical quotes to regular quotes and try again (`<meta name="author" content="My Name">`

Comment: Thank you all -- I pasted my code from here back into a fresh TextEdit window, saved as new file, and all the errors went away!

Comment: Silvia, while we're at it: also make sure you actually save your file as UTF-8, as your `meta` suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name=“author” content=“My Name”>
```

See how those quotes are curly? Your text editor's formatting typography for you in a way that's not helpful for web code. Change them to `""` quotes and you should be good to go.

```
<meta name="author" content="My Name">
```

Comment: ...and if their editor is doing that, there is a good chance it is also inserting other control characters or similar problematic stuff that can't even be seen. Plus, this is not the only thing wrong. Note the missing quotes around the `href` attribute values.

Comment: @domdom unfortunately, quotes around attribute values are not required unless there are spaces in the attribute value.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I didn't even know that! Is that a HTML5 thing or was it always like this? Thanks for letting me know in any case.

Comment: @domdom Sure thing. It's been valid since at least HTML 4.01 (and I believe 3.2, IIRC). If you go to the W3.org validator site and use their "Validate input" tab, and choose the "Validate HTML Fragment", you can enter something like `<img src=png.png alt=png>` and it'll say that's valid HTML 4.01 Strict.